# How to query Azure App Insights logs using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, logging

There is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/monitor-query-readme?view=azure-node-latest#logs-query) how it is possible to query

- LogAnalytics Workspace **Logs** or
- **Metrics** for individual resources
  using Node.Js:

But I could not find if there is an option to query **Logs** from AppInsights or from resource directly.

I need it to automate reporting of the performance, so I am planning to query `requests` table (we send logs using https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java). Currently report is done manually using Performance blade of the AppInsights - checking Avg and 99 percentile for requests with specific filters on URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup logs ingestion from your application to Log Analytics Workspace using Diagnostic Settings. For example, if you host your app in WebApp you can send `AppServiceHTTPLogs`. And then in your Node.JS app you can use `@azure/monitor-query` package with a similar query:

```
 let dataset=AppServiceHTTPLogs
      | where CsHost == 'PUT_YOUR_HOSTNAME_HERE'
      | where ScStatus == 200
      | where CsUriStem contains 'FILTER_BY_URL_IF_YOU_NEED_IT';
  dataset
  | summarize arg_max(TimeTaken, CsUriStem)
  | union(dataset
    | summarize avg(TimeTaken), percentiles(TimeTaken, 99)
    | extend CsUriStem='Overall')
```

That one is a close approximation of the performance blade from app insights.
And then your whole app could be

```
const azureLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId = "WORKSPACE_ID";
const logsQueryClient = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

export async function runWebAppPerformance(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
 
  const query = "PUT_YOUR_QUERY_HERE";
  const result = await logsQueryClient.queryWorkspace(    
    azureLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId,
    query,  
    {    
      startTime: startDate, endTime: endDate
    }
  );
   
  if (result.status === LogsQueryResultStatus.Success) {
    const tablesFromResult: LogsTable[] = result.tables;
 
    if (tablesFromResult.length === 0) {
      console.log(`No results for query`);
      return;
    }
 
    processTables(tablesFromResult);
  } else {
    console.log(`Error processing the query - ${result.partialError}`);
  }
}

async function processTables(tablesFromResult: LogsTable[]) {
  const table = tablesFromResult[0];

  const urlIndex = table.columnDescriptors.findIndex(c => c.name === "CsUriStem");
  const timeTakenIndex = table.columnDescriptors.findIndex(c => c.name === "TimeTaken");
  const avgIndex = table.columnDescriptors.findIndex(c => c.name === "avg_TimeTaken");
  const ninetyNineindex = table.columnDescriptors.findIndex(c => c.name === "percentile_TimeTaken_99");

  for (const row of table.rows) {
    if (row[urlIndex] === "Overall"){
      console.log(`${row[urlIndex]} (ms):`);
      console.log(`Average: ${row[avgIndex]}; \t 99%: ${row[ninetyNineindex]}`);      
    }
    else {
      console.log(`MAX (ms)`);
      console.log(`${row[urlIndex]}: \t ${row[timeTakenIndex]}`);      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to query Azure App Insights logs using Node.JS

- In Azure Portal, Create Application Insights Instance and Copy the Instrumentation key from the overview page

[image]

- Create a sample [NodeJS Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) in Visual Studio code
- We can add the instrumentation key in localhost or can be updated once after nodejs application is deployed to Azure.Here I have  added the  required application insight setting and deployed the App
- In `server.js`, add

```cs
let  appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup("cc580d32-a7eb-41d7-b0e0-90ea0889fd10");
appInsights.start();
```

- From the root folder of the Application, open the terminal and run

```cs
npm install applicationinsights --save
```

[image]

- Deploy the Application to Azure
- Browse the Application

***View Logs in Application Insights***

- Application Insights queries are based on KQL
- Navigate to Azure Portal => Your `Application Insights` Instance => `Logs`   under Monitoring = > Click on traces

> **Metrics** for individual resources using Node.Js

- Navigate to metrics under Monitoring

[image]

Please refer [Node.js services with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) for more information

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply.
My question was about querying AppInsights from Node.JS app, not how to send logs from it