# How to read Azure Logs programmatically?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, azure-application-insights

I'm developing a VSC extension, and I want to read data I logged in my application insights resource. In the attempt to read logs from Azure's Application Insights, using Azure's SDK I tried to use the following code (in javascript):

```
const { ApplicationInsightsDataClient } = require("@azure/applicationinsights-analytics");

async function retrieveLogs() {
  const connectionString = "InstrumentationKey=...";
  const query = "requests | take 10";

  const client = new ApplicationInsightsDataClient(connectionString);

  try {
    const result = await client.query(query);
    console.log(result.tables[0].rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving logs:", error);
  }
}

retrieveLogs();
```

But I wasn't successful, and now I'm clueless about how my VSC extension should read logged data from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read/get the logs from query logs using nodejs application
Steps:

- Create  application insights in azure portal and click on the Workspace  and copy the `workspaceid`.
- To run the query on the choosen Log Analytics workspace, the `logsQueryClient.queryWorkspace`method is used. The time for which logs should be queried is defined by the value of `Durations.twentyFourHours`.
- These are the packages installed.

`npm install @azure/identity @azure/monitor-query`

I have used the below code:

```js
const  {  DefaultAzureCredential  } = require("@azure/identity");
const  {  Durations,  LogsQueryClient,  LogsQueryResultStatus  } = require("@azure/monitor-query");
const  azureLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId = "2bc777d6-d9a2-4d3c-aafa-6b374205b20a";
const  logsQueryClient = new  LogsQueryClient(new  DefaultAzureCredential());
const  queryLogAnalytics = async  ()  =>  {
const  kustoQuery = `KubePodInventory`;
const  result = await  logsQueryClient.queryWorkspace(azureLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId,  kustoQuery,  {
duration:  Durations.twentyFourHours,
});
console.log(result);
if (result.status === LogsQueryResultStatus.Success) {
const  tablesFromResult = result.tables;
if (tablesFromResult.length === 0) {
console.log(`No results for query '${kustoQuery}'`);
return;
}
console.log(`This query has returned table(s) - `);
processTables(tablesFromResult);
}  else  {

console.log(`Error processing the query '${kustoQuery}' - ${result.partialError}`);
if (result.partialTables.length > 0) {
console.log(`This query has also returned partial data in the following table(s) - `);
processTables(result.partialTables);
}
}
};
const  processTables = (tables)  =>  {
tables.forEach((table)  =>  {
console.log(table);
});
};
queryLogAnalytics();
```

**Output:**

[image]

- For more details refer this  query Azure App Insights logs  [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#telemetryclient-api)  with   [Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs)  and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561612/how-to-query-azure-app-insights-logs-using-node-js#:%7E:text=Application%20Insights%20queries%20are%20based%20on%20KQL%20Navigate,resources%20using%20Node.Js%20Navigate%20to%20metrics%20under%20Monitoring).